# why vue multiselect delete every other input on click?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

basically, I'm writing a page in which, by entering the VAT number, the various fields are automatically filled in.
if we decide to change the province or municipality (the multiselects I mentioned above, which I use for the search function) all the inputs are reset / reported without value, I can't explain why or how to fix the problem

code snippet:

```
<div class="d-flex">
<input type="text" name="cap" id="cap" class="formInput required" placeholder="CAP" v-model="cap">
<multiselect class="formSelect required" v-model="comune" :options="comuni" :multiple="false" :close-on-select="true" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Comune" label="nome" track-by="id" :preselect-first="true" :limit="15"></multiselect>
<multiselect class="formSelect required" v-model="provincia" :options="province" :multiple="false" :close-on-select="true" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Provincia" label="sigla" track-by="id" :preselect-first="true" :limit="15"></multiselect>
```

I tried to read the documentation but I couldn't find anything about it, technically it shouldn't eliminate all the other inputs I guess, so I can't understand this

Comment: Can you not share more complete code? It's important to look at how you define your data,  reactivity, if you have any watchers, whether something else is modifying your form or object, etc etc.